How to create this widget with genie effect in flutter?
Animation
Hello Flutter community,
I'm trying to create an animation in Flutter similar to what is shown in the GIF below:
What I Want to Achieve:
I have a draggable widget (a box) that the user can move around.
When the user presses the "Magic!" button, the widget should smoothly animate to a predefined position on the screen.
I have implemented the draggable functionality using Draggable and DragTarget widgets. But was unable to achieve the desired output.

Try to this: add_to_cart_animation 2.0.4
https://pub.dev/packages/add_to_cart_animation

This is not quite similar to the animation but pretty close.
